# Make an input repeat according to the number of characters

Tags: python, while-loop, count, character

I have been trying to make a loop in Python that counts the number of characters in a word typed by the user and then prints that same word according to the number of characters in the word used.
This is what I got:

```
print("Please tell me a word")
word = str(input())

characters = count_char(word)
count = 0 

while (count < characters):
  print(word)

  count = count + 1
```

Obviously the `characters = count_char(word)` doesn't work and that's where I need help. I have seen many posts related to how to count characters in a word but none of them seemed applicable for my case. 
I would appreciate any help :D

Thank you

---

Thank you for your fast answers and support!!
here is the solution I came to:

```
print("Please tell me a word")
word = str(input())

numOfChar = len(word)

for count in range (0, numOfChar, 1):
  print(word)
```

Comment: There's already a function, it's `len`, short for length.

Comment: Please consider putting example in code format.

Comment: what's the desired output you want?

Answer (score 1):

The straight-forward way to do this is to use the `len` function to get the length of the input word, and then use a `for` loop over a `range` of that size:

```
word = input("Please tell me a word: ")
for i in range(len(word)):
    print(word)
```

**test**

```
Please tell me a word: Alex
Alex
Alex
Alex
Alex
```

A more efficient way is to create the desired number of copies of the word in a list and then use `.join` to join the copies together into a single string, using the newline character as the separator between each word.

```
word = input("Please tell me a word: ")
print('\n'.join([word] * len(word)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I made it work: 

print("Please tell me a word")
word = str(input())

#count the number of characters in the answer
numOfChar = len(word)

for count in range (0, numOfChar, 1):
  print(word)

Answer (score 0):

use `len(word)` to get the length of the characters of the input and then do this do repeat the code

```
x=0
while x<len(word):
    #your code
    x+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Please tell me a word")
word = str(input())

characters = len(word)

for each in range(0 < characters):
  print(word)
```

Use `len(word)` to count length of a word.

Updated: Used forloop instead of while.

Comment: That worked as well but I found that using a FOR statement would make the code smaller and easier to read. but thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of characters of a string/word with the function `len()`
the you can use a for loop to to print the word according to the number of characters using the `range()` function:

```
print("Please tell me a word:")
word = input()
for x in range(len(word)):
 print(word)
```